# Exception thrown when setting HttpClientHandler credentials in Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I know that this is technically still a preview, and this might be a known (or unknown) issue but I could also be missing something obvious (especially as not being able to set credentials sounds important enough that Microsoft would probably have fixed it already).

To reproduce:

```
public class Credentials : ICredentials
{
    public NetworkCredential GetCredential(Uri uri, string authType)
    {
        return new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    }
}

public App()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    try
    {
        var credentials = new Credentials();
        var httpc = new HttpClientHandler();
        httpc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        httpc.Credentials = credentials;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

The exception details are:

Message:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: format
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_Credentials(ICredentials value)
at WinTenTest.App..ctor()
```

I mean, it's clear what the internal problem is, but I have no idea why. The exception is thrown without GetCredential in the Credentials class is called, so it's not that.

The same code works perfectly in Windows 8.1 apps.

I'm using VS2015 RC, the latest W10 build and the latest dev tools, so I'm not out of date there either.

Comment: `httpc.Credentials = credentials;` Aren't you supposed to be calling `GetCredentials`?

Comment: HAH! That actually does fix the problem. There's still something weird going on (setting a custom Credentials object works in W8.1, plus AFAIK my way lets you provide multiple credentials (one per URI*authType) and the correct credential will be passed to HttpClient when needed), but you are totally correct in this case. Can't believe I missed it!

Comment: Sometimes the little things get by :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Yuval Itzchakov commented below the question, in this case you can just do

```
httpc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("", "")
```

OR

```
httpc.Credentials = credentials.GetCredential(uri, authType).
```

I'm still intrigued as to why W10 has broken what worked in W8.1, but it's less important now.